# How to produce approximate fraction numbers from irrational number on MatLab?

Tags: php, matlab, fractions

I have a clumsy PHP code that I've used to get approximate fraction numbers for irrational numbers like pi, phi, square root of 2, 3 and so on. I'd like to get a formula that I can use on MatLab and get both data table and draw a plot based on approximate fraction numbers. Maybe someone already can grab from this but I'll provide PHP code to complement the case:

```
$n = phi(); # irrational number (imaginary/complex number?)
$x = 500; # how many numbers to check
$max = 50; # how many instances to show
$precision = 0.0001;

# check every i against every j and make a comparison how near their values are to each other
for ($i=1; $i<$x; $i++) {
    for ($j=1; $j<$x; $j++) {
        # compared value is stored on array. very distant numbers needs to be discarded ($precision) or array gets easily too big, limit 64k
        if (($d = abs(($n - ($i/$j)))) && $d > $precision) continue;
        $c[] = array($i, $j, $d);
    }
}

# sort comparison chart by third index (2)
array_qsort($c, 2);

# print max best values from the sorted comparison chart
$count = count($c);
echo "closest fraction numbers for $n from $count calculated values are:<br />\n<br />\n";
$r = 0;
foreach ($c as $abc) {
    $r++;
    $d = $abc[0]/$abc[1];
    echo $abc[0] . '/' . $abc[1] . ' = ' . $d . ' (' . round($abc[2]*(1/$precision), 10) . ')' . "<br />\n";
    if ($r > $max) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more efficient algorithms, here is one:

```
function [a, b, c] = approxfrac( r, precision )
a = floor(r);
r = r - a;
if r==0,
    b=0;
    c=1;
    return
end
p1 = 0; q1 = 1;
p2 = 1; q2 = 1;
b = p1+p2;
c = q1+q2;
while abs(r-b/c) > precision,
    if r>b/c,
        p1 = b; q1 = c;
    else
        p2 = b; q2 = c;
    end
    b = p1+p2;
    c = q1+q2;
end
end
```

Comment: Great! I modified it a bit to get fourth return value:

`d = (a*c)+b;)` So I call `[a, b, c, d] = approxfrac(pi, 0.01);` -> `3, 1, 7, 22` where fraction is `22/7` or `3 1/7`

I would accept that as a partial solution, because I still want to get an array of n best solutions like on my PHP code. Can this function be used for it just by shifting precision?

Comment: Then you can keep track of all b and c values in the while loop by adding them to an array and returning those arrays for b and c. At every iteration, b/c ratio is closer to the desired number (r-a) than previous iteration, therefore they are already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function for that: [rat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rat.html)